# Systemd: Find dependants of service

Tags: systemd, dependencies

```
systemctl list-dependencies postgres
```

Will list all the dependencies of the `postgres` service.
How do I find all the **dependents** of a service (or unit, or target)?

Comment: Are you looking for the `--reverse` flag?

Comment: Yes, I just spotted it in the manpage and was about to answer my own question. I ran a few tests, most of them add up. It seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: However it is not exactly what I wanted. It seems that it will only list dependents that are explicitly declared with "RequiredBy", "WantedBy", etc.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies systemd-sysusers.service --all --reverse
systemd-sysusers.service
● └─sysinit.target
●   ├─accounts-daemon.service
●   │ └─graphical.target
●   ├─acpid.path
●   │ └─paths.target
●   │   └─basic.target
●   │     └─multi-user.target
●   │       └─graphical.target
```

`man systemctl`:

```
   list-dependencies [UNIT...]
       Shows units required and wanted by the specified units.
       This recursively lists units following the Requires=,
       Requisite=, ConsistsOf=, Wants=, BindsTo= dependencies. If
       no units are specified, default.target is implied.

       By default, only target units are recursively expanded.
       When --all is passed, all other units are recursively
       expanded as well.

       Options --reverse, --after, --before may be used to change
       what types of dependencies are shown.

       Note that this command only lists units currently loaded
       into memory by the service manager. In particular, this
       command is not suitable to get a comprehensive list at all
       reverse dependencies on a specific unit, as it won't list
       the dependencies declared by units currently not loaded.
```

Comment: Would a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` help to remedy the _"... as it won't list the dependencies declared by units currently not loaded"_ argument ?